# Restoring state after rotate display

Tags: android, rotation, state, restore

I have in fragment two of my own widgets. These widgets have edit text and textview. If i write something to bottom edit text and rotate display, text appears in both edit texts. If i write text to upper edit text and rotate display, text dissapear. I think that this is caused because that edit texts have same ID. Is there any better solution than save texts from both edittexts and restore it on m yown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

You need to override [`onSavedInstanceState(Bundle state)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) and save the values of your view to that `state` bundle.

Then, in `onCreate` or `onRestoreInstanceState` repopulate your views from the value of the bundle passed in the two aforementioned methods. Your views are *sometimes* likely to repopulate but this is not always the case.

Comment: Yes, i am familiar with this method, but my question was if is any way to make android do it for me. Because if you have edit texts with different ids it works. But because of my own widgets i cannot have different ids

Comment: You should probably implement [`onSaveInstanceState`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onSaveInstanceState()) then?

Comment: when fragment is set to retain instance, bundle in onCreateView and onViewCreated is null.

Answer (score 0):

you can also put this in your manifest.xml

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

Comment: This isnt the best practice